# Aligning objects

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

This is the complete design I'm going for:
[image]

And this is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/rlesko/f3R7r/4/

A couple of questions:

1. Why doesn't a code `margin-left` do nothing when changed for the object `#date`?
2. Do you know of a code that I can use to center a `#separator` object on a `.post-bg` (the white background)? I used `margin-left` for that in my CSS.
3. How can I align the `<h2>` text's right border to the `<p>` text's right border but keep the `<h2>` text alignment to the right?
4. Why doesn't a custom font code work for this fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lots of points are best put into separate questions, but anyway...

1. It *does* work! [Margin is set to 550px to prove](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/f3R7r/9/)
2. You can use `margin: 0 auto;` on the separator element to center it. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/f3R7r/14/).
3. Use `text-align: justify;` for your desired text alignment on both sides. [See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/f3R7r/17/).
4. I think it has to do with not being able to serve fonts cross-domain. But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
1) Silly me, I did watch out for all the space on the left and tried only to about 100px.

2) Great, thanks.

3) No, I want the rightmost side of the title (the word 'ONE') to be in line with the right border of the body (the paragraphs) BUT I want the text inside the title to look as it is i.e. that it is aligned to the left. Do I have to use margin-right or is there some other way? If I use margin-right, the rest of the objects misbehave and I can't align it.

Comment: TO align the text to the right, use `text.align: right;`. Margin is the space outside of the edge of the element.

Comment: I know that.
Look at this pic: http://i39.tinypic.com/24f9xmv.jpg The red lines are showing what needs to align to what.

Comment: I tested your fiddle, apart from the fact that mediafire produced a bad link, it seems you cannot link to another domain. Even a clean @ff code linked to existing files didn't work. :/

Answer (score 0):

1. The margin works, but the h5 is weird and the appropriate margin to place it like you want to is :  margin: 0 0 0 135px; (tested in firebug)
2. margin: 0 auto;
3. text-align: justify ?
4. Because media fire makes a redirection and transforms your url into : http://www.mediafire.com/?f9selsldbgm6dnw and then only you can dl the file. This is not a real direct download, that's why your font won't work. Upload it on you own domain for example.

Try this one instead : http://www.amws.fr/Univers.ttf

Edit : I'd also suggest using a complete @font-face code, so that all browsers support your css well :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LiberationSansRegular';
    src: url('http://www.amws.fr/Univers.eot');
    src: url('http://www.amws.fr/Univers.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.amws.fr/Univers.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.amws.fr/Univers.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.amws.fr/Univers.svg#LiberationSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```